# Вывести сумму товаров таблице Opencart

Tags: php

Есть цикл в шаблоне, который выводит количество выбраных товаров в админке клиентом:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { 
echo $product['quantity'];
} ?>
```

Как сделать в этом цикле вывод сумму количества выбраных товаров?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал вывести так:

```
foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
          <?php 
          $total_q = $product['quantity'];
          $total_q += $total_q;
             ?>
          <?php } echo $total_q;
```

Но выводиться только "2", хотя должно вывести "4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно присвоить $total_q=0 за пределами цикла(до foreach), а в цикле написать

```
$total_q += $product['quantity'];
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Сработало.